# GitHub Actions not following rules set in yaml file

Tags: git, github-actions

I'm trying to configure a GitHub Actions to ignore certain `paths`, `files`, or `branches` when I push is made. I may not be understanding on this works.

My current workflow:

1. Create a new branch called `2.7.1`.
2. Commit and push changes to `2.7.1`.
3. In GitHub, I create a `pull request` and merge to `main` but then the workflow starts?

The files in the commit are specified to be ignored as well as the branch name:

```
on:
  push:
    paths-ignore:
      - '.github/**'
      - '.streamlit/**'
      - 'api/**'
      - 'pages/**'
      - 'CHANGELOG.md'
      - 'Dockerfile'
      - '.dockerignore'
      - '.gitignore'
      - '.pylintrc'
      - 'README.md'
      - 'streamlit_app.py'
      - 'style.css'
    branches:
      - "main"

  pull_request:
    branches-ignore:
      - '2.*'
      - '3.*'
      - '4.*'
```

With these configuration, I don't understand why the workflow is being triggered:
[image]

Comment: Why are you using PR because according to the docs (https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#pull_request_target) "Avoid using this event if you need to build or run code from the pull request." I think you are looking for branch-ignore on paths.

Comment: You've configured your workflow to run on pushes to `main`. That's exactly what you get when you merge your pull request to `main`. It sounds like your workflow is working as designed.

Comment: Sorry I meant use path, but I think a mixture of @larsks and my comment go together. The question is more about what the function is doing. My guess is you should be able to stick to push. Just have multiple files that match multiple branches and handle as appropriate.

Comment: @larsks - I figured that’s what was happening. I guess I can ignore files and directories from the `pull-request` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible. Filter `branches-ignore` applies just to a pull-request event. So when you merge code you have a new event and there is no something like a source branch filter.

You can try to switch to tags, and then create a workflow with a tag filter. Then just do not create a tag on branches you don't want to run your workflow.

If you also edit a message before the merge and instruct to skip a run

> Workflows that would otherwise be triggered using on: push or on: pull_request won't be triggered if you add any of the following strings to the commit message in a push, or the HEAD commit of a pull request:
>
> - [skip ci]
> - [ci skip]
> - [no ci]
> - [skip actions]
> - [actions skip]

Comment: I don't think this is the behavior requested. This will still build if it isn't one of those files and you will still see the green check.

Comment: Could you explain what would you want to achieve on push? When workflow should be triggered and when not?

Comment: @KrzysztofMadej - I’m wanting to merge pull requests to `main` but if the pull requests is coming from a branch that starts with `2` or `3` or `4`, then it should NOT start the workflow. Not sure if this is possible though… I thought that’s what `branches-ignore` would do. I think I’m misunderstanding though since the push is still going to `main`.

Comment: This is not possible. branches-ignores applies to pull request events not to push events.

Comment: Please check my edit. Could you consider upvoting my reply if it was helpful for you?

Answer (score 0):

This was the ChatGPT answer and seems pretty accurate.

```
name: PR Merge to Main

on:
  pull_request:
    types:
      - closed

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    
    steps:
      - name: Check branch name
        run: |
          if [ "${{ github.event.pull_request.base.ref }}" == "main" ] && [[ "${{ github.event.pull_request.head.ref }}" =~ ^2 ]]; then
            echo "Running workflow for PR merge to main from branch starting with 2"
          else
            echo "Skipping workflow for this PR"
            exit 0
          fi
          
      # Add your workflow steps below
      # Example: run tests, build, deploy, etc.
```

Not sure there is a way to do it with just the gh action filters.